# Вопрос про onclick()

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код

```
<div onclick="a()">
    <div onclick="b()">

    </div>    
</div>
```

Если нажать на внутренний блок сначала выполнится b() потом а()

Как сделать, чтобы выполнялась только b(); т.е только то, что навешано на елемент по которому кликают, вне зависимости от того, что навешано на его родительские элементы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
const a = () => console.log('a')
const b = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('b');
}
```

```css
.c1 { width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px red solid; }
.c2 { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px blue solid; }
```

```html
<div class="c1" onclick="a()">
  <div class="c2" onclick="b(event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Нужно использовать `stopPropogation`. В браузерах есть механизм ["всплытия"](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling) события. Поэтому сначала срабатывает клик на внутреннем элементе, а потом на внешнем. Что бы избежать этого и используют `stopPropagation`

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const child = document.getElementById('child');

const onclick = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('Покажется один раз');
}

parent.onclick = onclick
child.onclick = onclick
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Испортил репу =)

Answer (score 2):

Пример чтоб заработал именно ваш код:

```html
<div onclick="a()">
    <div onclick="event.stopPropagation(); b()">

    </div>    
</div>
```

Но так обычно не делают. Обычно делают как-то так:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function b(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ну и дальше свой код
}
</script>

<div onclick="a()">
    <div onclick="b(event)">

    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Всем спасибо stopPropagation() то что нужно.